# Can cmake ignore the changes of comment

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a very huge project, it contains lots of modules and they shared some basic header files.

The project is managed by CMake.

Today I found that if I make a tiny change on some comments in a basic header file, it would cause all of modules recompilation since they all include this basic header file.

Is it possible to make CMake ignore the comment changes?

Comment: cmake doesn't try to figure out what changed, it just sees if all dependencies are up to date.

Comment: Actually, cmake doesn't even do that--it generates build files that will have the build system check if the files are up to date.  This probably isn't possible at the cmake level, and I can't think of any solution that's less trouble than just grabbing lunch after finishing documentation.

Comment: @StephenNewell "check if the files are up to date" --- what do you mean by "up to date"? Do you mean that CMake checks the modification time of the files?

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of makefiles, but it at least applies to ninja as well (I assume the other generators also do this).  A target (libfoo) has dependencies on various things (other libraries, source files, generating stuff, etc.) and the build system just looks at what's out of date.  If foo.c is newer than stuff that depends on it (libfoo), then those targets need to get rebuilt.  Repeat until whatever target the end-user wanted to build is up to date with all dependencies.  You can actually get ninja to spit out a dependency graph at the file level, but I forget the command right now.

Comment: @StephenNewell  Thanks man, I got it.